# magento Error on mail send

Tags: magento-1.9, email, localhost, smtp

I install `Aschroder_SMTPPro` but mail not send it gives error

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with
>   code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed  in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\charge\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php on line 206

Anyone Have solution For this ??

SSL Support Is also enable
http://prntscr.com/hp1c9g

Comment: Its issue related to SSL not working properly on your server. Please check below URL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827192/phpmailer-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed

Comment: im using it in local

Comment: Do you use a virtual host like "mysite.magento.local"? Or is it just localhost? Also how did you generate your openssl certificate? And to what host does it point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download cacert.pem file from following link
    https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

open php.ini file

and paste following path in php.ini file

openssl.cafile="c:/xampp/cacert.pem"

Answer (score 0):

I was also having similar issue with Aschroder_SMTPPro but installed another extension and it worked, find extension link below:

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp

Comment: its for Magento2 , im getting error in magento1

Comment: Ohh Isee, missed to check right Magento version. Have you tried with different smtp ports i.e. 25, 465 and 587?

Comment: no there is no any port issue just open scrrenshot and show error